# Interaction of processes in Java

Tags: java, process, interaction

Suppose I have a Java application. I want to run another Java application from current (not a thread - a separate application) to calculate some function and them get the result to my first application to output it. How can I implement this?

Comment: google "java ipc" or "java inter-process communication"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What comes to mind:

- RMI
- shared memory
- piping
- calling 1st from 2nd
- sending signal
- socket programming (REST, SOAP, etc.)

Comment: Yeah thanks, I read a little about RMI already. I just would like to see an example of code where another application is launched from within my application.